# Collecting comment data from multiple Rar files without unzipping

Tags: python, rar

I wanted to collect comment data of a zip file from multiple files(as the optional comment you get on the side when opening a Zip or a Rar file)

but now I realize that they are not Zip but Rar files, what do i need to change in order for it to work on a Rar file?

```
import unicodedata
from zipfile import ZipFile 

rootFolder = u"C:/Users/user/Desktop/archives/"
zipfiles = [os.path.join(rootFolder, f) for f in
os.listdir(rootFolder)] for zfile in zipfiles:
    print("Opening: {}".format(zfile))
    with ZipFile(zfile, 'r') as testzip:
        print(testzip.comment) # comment for entire zip
        l = testzip.infolist() #list all files in archive
        for finfo in l:
            # per file/directory comments
            print("{}:{}".format(finfo.filename, finfo.comment))
```

Comment: You can try rarfile - https://rarfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Comment: do i need to install it or does it come built in with python?

Comment: you have to install it. Use pip.

Comment: alright managed to install it, should be as straightforward to just change everything that mentions zipfile to rarfile?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RARFILE module. `ZipFile.comment()` can only get a comment object from the ZIP file.